# Issue saving GeoPoint to a DB/Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-server, pfobject, geopoints

I have code like this to take an object in Core Data and save it to a mLab database, working with Heroku.

```
// item is an NSManagedObject ....
var dataDict:[String:AnyObject]
dataDict = ["name": item.valueForKey("name") as! String,
            "address": item.valueForKey("address") as! String]

let gpsStr = item.valueForKey("gPS") as! String,
commaRange = gpsStr.rangeOfString(","),
gPS = PFGeoPoint(latitude: Double(gpsStr.substringToIndex((commaRange?.startIndex)!))!,
                 longitude: Double(gpsStr.substringFromIndex((commaRange?.endIndex)!))!)
dataDict["gPS"] = gPS

let parse_Object = PFObject(className: "TheGoodClass", dictionary: dataDict)

parse_Object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
    if (succeeded) {
        print("IT all went RIGHT")
    } else {
        print("IT all went WRONG")
    }
}
```

When running it I get this kind of error message:

```
.... [Error]: schema mismatch for TheGoodClass.gPS; expected String but got GeoPoint (Code: 111, Version: 1.12.0)
IT all went WRONG
```

I don't understand why a String is expected here.
I want a GeoPoint and not a String. What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you check in your parse-dashboard if the property is type of String ?

Comment: How can I do that? I never set any property in the parse-dashboard (on Heroku). They are all created when uploading a record with PFObject from my app.

Comment: @ Ran Hassid I finally found out and solved my problem. Your question gave me the right hint. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cool i am very happy that it works for you :)